# Retrieve a list of all keys stored in Redis (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, redis

Is there a function in the redis-rb gem that returns a list of all the keys stored in the DB? My end goal is to iterate over all my key/value pairs and do perform some action on them.

Answer (score 45):

Sure, the redis-rb exposes all of the Redis commands and represents them as methods on your client object.

```
redis.keys('*')
```

Comment: `.keys` will cause blocking and performance issues. `.scan` or `.scan_each` should be used instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143659/ruby-redis-client-scan-vs-keys

Answer (score 31):

If you have any substantial amount of records in your db, kernel will kill your `redis.keys` because it will be taking too much RAM.

What you want is extracting keys in batches. **redis-rb** has a wonderful method for this (not present in **redis** itself):

```
    redis.scan_each(match: 'user:*') do |resume_key_name|
        resume_key_name #=> "user:12"
    end
```

If you want all the keys, just don't use the `match` option.

Comment: This was extremely slow for me; it took like 15 seconds to return on a Redis database with only 5.6K keys.

Comment: @AbeVoelker You can use redis with `pipelined`, which will be faster

Comment: see @Alex answer. simple and straightforward

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维, his answer will fail for too many keys. But it is nice for a couple hundred.

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 , using `.keys` is discouraged because of blocking issues and performance.

Answer (score 8):

`redis.keys`
this will return the result in array form.

more info : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ezmobius/redis-rb/Redis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143659/ruby-redis-client-scan-vs-keys