# ruby redis client scan vs keys

Tags: ruby, redis

I am looking for some documentation for the ruby client for redis with no luck.
I am using keys, but I've heard their performance in production redis is terrible.

```
$redis = Redis.new(host: Settings.redis_host, port: Settings.redis_port)
keys = $redis.keys("prefix*")
```

Want to switch to `$redis.scan("prefix*")` but I didn't find any examples for it.
also tried

```
keys = $redis.scan(0, {match: "key:1?"})
Redis::CommandError: ERR syntax error
keys = $redis.scan(0, match: "key:1?")
Redis::CommandError: ERR syntax error
```

appreciate a little light on this.
Thanks.

Edit:
After updating the redis client from 3.0.4 to 3.0.7 the

```
keys = $redis.scan(0, match: "prefix*")
```

worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
keys = $redis.scan(0, match: 'prefix?')
```

[Here](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L2349-L23668) is the "documentation" you need.

Be sure to also read the [official documentation](http://redis.io/commands/scan) of `SCAN`.

Comment: hi, getting `keys = $redis.scan(0, match: 'prefix*')
Redis::CommandError: ERR syntax error`

Comment: Are you using the redis-rb driver? If so, which version? Also can you try now with the updated answer?

Comment: hi, after updating from redis 3.0.4 to 3.0.7, this syntax worked.